# How do I set a broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I want to set a broadcast receiver to run some function when it gets the broadcast message, in this example, I want to catch the download's manager intent:

```
DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE
```

I looked at the Android API examples and haven't found a way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read this first:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Then look here for examples.

*Android Samples:* http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/appwidget/ExampleBroadcastReceiver.html

*Blog post:* http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/01/basics-of-android-part-ii-intent-receivers/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE) ){
      // do something
    }
  }

 registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that inherits from `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class MyDownloadCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    }
}
```

And then register this class in your application manifest like so:

```
    <receiver android:enabled="true" 
                android:name="MyDownloadCompleteReceiver"
                android:label="downloadCompleteReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```