# How to use Android DownloadManager?

Tags: android, download

I want to download a file to SDCard with Android DownloadManager class:

```
Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(url));
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename); //set destination dir
long downloadId = downloader.enqueue(request);
```

But I always get download status=16(STATUS_FAILED), and reason=1008(ERROR_CANNOT_RESUME). I have already included android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in the manifest.

When i commented out the

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);
```

and use the default download folder, it's OK. But I don't know where is the file goes, the localUri I get from the result is something like:

```
content://downloads/my_downloads/95
```

I don't know how to copy the file to SDCard.

What I want is download a file to *SDCard*. Could someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

You can retrieve file path from localUri like this:

```
public static String getFilePathFromUri(Context c, Uri uri) {
    String filePath = null;
    if ("content".equals(uri.getScheme())) {
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaColumns.DATA };
        ContentResolver contentResolver = c.getContentResolver();

        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, filePathColumn, null,
                null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
    } else if ("file".equals(uri.getScheme())) {
        filePath = new File(uri.getPath()).getAbsolutePath();
    }
    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, working perfectly with DownloadManager

Answer (score 13):

`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString()` gives me `/mnt/sdcard/downloads`

And I'm able to use the downloaded file in `onReceive (ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE)`

```
long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
Query query = new Query();
query.setFilterById(downloadId);
Cursor cur = dm.query(query);

if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
    int columnIndex = cur.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
    if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == cur.getInt(columnIndex)) {
        String uriString = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));

        File mFile = new File(Uri.parse(uriString).getPath());
        ....

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(c, R.string.fail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I get only "content://downloads/my_downloads/539" with this code and no local path.

Comment: Depending on the Android version you either get a file:// back (on android < 4.2) or a content:// (on android 4.2 and up). so this answer only applies to android lower 4.2 and on 4.2 and up the content would need to be resolved with the answer below by Min.