# webview, open file with , after download

Tags: java, android, android-webview

helo im using android webview,  i try to open file after download with this code : but have error when opening file , something wrong on my code , any one have idea ?
i think my problem are on this line:

```
  intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(request.toString()), "application/*");
```

```
//handle downloading

        webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                        request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                        String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                        request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                        request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                        request.setDescription("Downloading file....");
                        request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                        dm.enqueue(request);

                        
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(request.toString()), "application/*");
                            startActivity(intent);

                            
                    } else {
                        Log.d("permission", "permission denied to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE - requesting it");
                        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                        requestPermissions(permissions, 1);
                    }
                }
            }



        });
```

Comment: You're using wrong tag. It should be `Java`, not `Javascript`. There are a lot of differences between them.

Comment: yes im sorry i have change to java

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine. With an emulator I get the same error with opening file. But with the a real device it working fine. Ergo: The emulator is having issues. Try to update it and restart everything.

Comment: i use my galaxy s10 like emulator i think the code is working on old android version , but not on android 11 api 30

Comment: I took a look and indeed I used Android 10 Api 28. So it isn't working for newer versions.

Comment: ahh thank yu for the confirmation, :) , so no solution for new versions ?

Comment: I found this post that can help you to modify your code, to get it work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239996/android-downloadmanager-api-opening-file-after-download

Comment: thank you i will try now, did you have any chat contact ? maybe you can help me if i send you full code